# Selection of covariates for partial correlation?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, pearson-r, partial-correlation

Are there any recommendations on procedures to identify relevant variables for a partial correlation between $r(X, Y)$?
To me, it appears most reasonable to only include those $Z_1, Z_2,\ldots,Z_n$ as covariates that are correlated with **both** $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Could you please give us some context?  What is the meaning of "relevance" of a variable for this purpose?  Are you trying to claim that if $Z_i$ is uncorrelated with either $X$ or $Y$ then the partial correlation won't change when $Z_i$ is included with the other variables or not?  If that's the case, consider the situation with $n=1$ and let $Z$ be orthogonal to $X$ but not to $Y;$ for instance, let $X=(1,0),$ $Z=(0,1),$ and $Y=(1,1).$ What are the partial correlations with and without $Z$?

Comment: In brief, I examine the relationship between an objective measure and a clinical test. Literature suggests factors that impact either one or both of these measurements. For partial correlation, it appears more logical to me to only include covariates that are associated with both measures, and not only one of those.
If the latter would be the case, then one could just fit a regression model, as both yield same results... @whuber